# ProcessBuilder works for javac but not my intended program (return -1073741819)

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

```
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "\"C:\\Program Files\\PDF24\\pdf24-Ocr.exe\"", "-outputFile", "C:\\ocr\\06062022120232-0001_color300_ocred2.pdf", "C:\\OCR\\06062022120232-0001_color300.pdf");
/////   ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1.1\\bin\\javac.exe\"", "--help");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        final Process process = builder.start();

        // Watch the process
        /////watch(process);
        
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null; 
        try {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        /////process.waitFor(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES); /////
        System.out.println("before wait for ...");
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\nExited Code : "+exitCode);
```

Comment: Might be related, or might not, but why go through CMD? Why not just invoke the executable directly?

Comment: cannot run executable directly, seem need cmd

Comment: anyone can help me ??

Comment: What happens when you run that exact command in cmd.exe manually?

Comment: when execute manually, it can produce the output

Comment: PS C:\Users\trand\eclipse-workspace\ocr> cmd /c "C:\Program Files\PDF24\pdf24-Ocr.exe" -outputFile C:\ocr\06062022120232-0001_color300_ocred2.pdf C:\OCR\06062022120232-0001_color300.pdf


================
"C:\Program Files\PDF24\tesseract\tesseract.exe" -v
----------------
================
"C:\Program Files\PDF24\gs\bin\gswinc.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dNEWPDF=false  -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r300 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sDEVICE=png16m "-sOutputFile=C:\Users\trand\AppData\Local\Temp\PDF24\ocr_58950562_2921103835_0.

Comment: What if you get rid of the escaped quotes (i.e., `\"`) in the third argument (the one after the `"/c"` argument)? Since the argument is its own element in the string array, I would expect `ProcessBuilder` to quote it for you. Perhaps that's messing things up.

Comment: it does not work as the \" is needed since there is a space in "Program Files"

Comment: I know there's a space. But the `ProcessBuilder` will _"quote" it for you_. At least, that's how I remember it working for me in the past. (_Edit: Just tried it myself. The escaped quotes were not needed; however, nor did their presence cause any problems_)

Comment: In fact, I have taken away before and it really cause a problem

Comment: In between, their presence did not cause any problem as you said because it works for javac -version. May be my intended problem take too long to run, but I really have no idea :(